# PHP - PHP Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset in function

Tags: php

I have the following PHP function:

```
function readDataFile_array($dataFileName) {
    if (file_exists($dataFileName)) {
        $readFile = fopen($dataFileName, 'r');
        $previousData = fread($readFile, filesize($dataFileName));
        fclose($readFile);
        $previousData = unserialize($previousData);
    } else {
        $previousData = null;
    }
    return $previousData;
}
```

I'm getting the following error: `PHP Notice:  unserialize(): Error at offset 416687 of 416690 bytes`

The data to be read by the function is being saved using the following:

```
function writeDataFile_array($dataFileName, $insertData) {
    $insertData = serialize($insertData);
    $writeFile = fopen($dataFileName, 'w') or die('Unable to open file!');
    fwrite($writeFile, $insertData);
    fclose($writeFile);
}
```

I'm not sure why I'm getting the error that refers to `$previousData = unserialize($previousData);`

Comment: you dont have strip slashes on or anything like that?

Comment: No, the data being saved is an array

Comment: yeah but you serialize it to a string, I meant to say magic quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are f-reading the wrong chunk size.

The EOF seems to be added to the file size.
Try to get the file by using file_get_contents() which is the proper way to read file data.

```
$previousData = file_get_contents($dataFileName);
```